# IOS integrated unity 4.6.3 project(64-bit). Appear the following such a mistake, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have matched all the configuration of the two project, and import the frameworks. and the error is：

```
ld: framework not found -stdlib=libstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You may need to create a new build instead of overwriting. Also make sure you have IL2CPP compiler selected, post screenshot of your player settings for iOS unity.

Comment: i have set Scripting Backend and Architecture ，and matched all configuration with the project build for unity.

Comment: i dont konw  how to post images, so i get some links :http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/large/005M0d4gjw1etgsj0fntqj30jp037t8t.jpg http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/large/005M0d4gjw1etgsiziy7tj30g600q0sl.jpg http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/large/005M0d4gjw1etgsj2qnjsj30v907tmy5.jpg http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/large/005M0d4gjw1etgsj3isvrj30vg08mdgn.jpg http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/large/005M0d4gjw1etgsj48jopj30w10myq5h.jpg http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/mw690/005M0d4gjw1etgsj23rcgj30lw06xjs0.jpg http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/005M0d4gjw1etgsj1340zj30ic03ot8u.jpg http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/large/005M0d4gjw1etgsj4vu0yj312q082adq.jpg